# Buffer overflow Xuggler

Tags: java, webcam, xuggler

To capture video from a web-camera, I used the example code from the [DisplayWebcamVideo.java](https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DisplayWebcamVideo.java)

I run the code with the parameters `vfwcap` and `0`, it always shows an error:

```
ERROR org.ffmpeg - [vfwcap @ 000000000039A320] real-time buffer [number]% full!frame dropped!
```

Tell me please how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the README File? [ReadMe](https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/README)

Have you download the DLL it requests? Have you read the comments before the

```
public class DisplayWebcamVideo
```

Have you got the right driver name? and device name?

Comment: WEB-camera is automatically detected at startup. With regards to the drivers - I do not know how to get the name, the answer to the internet can not find.

The rest - all read and set.